# Detectar cuando la página es mobile y restringir acceso

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Estoy haciendo una app y estoy en el paso básico. Necesito que cuando la pantalla llegue al breakpoint de mobile ( `max-width:600px` ) Se renderice otro componente, si no, entonces se rendericen las demás vistas. No está funcionando, el `mobileQuery.matches` en cualquier dimensión queda en `false`

Tengo esto en **app.component.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'maho';
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
  private queryListener: () => void;

  constructor( changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher ) {
    this.mobileQuery   = media.matchMedia('max-width: 600px');
    this.queryListener = () => changeDetector.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addEventListener('change', this.queryListener);
  }

}
```

Y este es el código de **app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="this.mobileQuery.matches">
  VISTA NO DISPONIBLE
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!this.mobileQuery.matches">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-container>
```

Me estoy basando en este [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnvrvknqgym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts) de Angular Material que lo hace para un diseño distinto en su panel de navegación

Comment: Escuchar propuestas no seria una respuesta basada en opiniones?

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo quité

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu propuesta es correcta, y AngularMaterial es la mejor opción, pero el único detalle es que te faltan los paréntesis para que funcione `(max-width: 600px)`

```
this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");
```

Comment: Ajaaaa. Hasta a un Senior se le van estas cosas. Gracias crack.